# How to find the conditional expectation of dependent random variables?

Tags: probability, conditional-expectation, bivariate-distributions

I am wondering how to find an expression for $E[X | Y \geq a]$ for $X \sim N(\mu_X, \sigma_X^2)$ and $Y \sim N(\mu_Y, \sigma_Y^2)$ and a given constant $a \in R$ in the case that $X$ and $Y$ are not independent?

Comment: What have you attempted so far? In particular, since this seems like it can be solved by simply calculating an integral, have you tried that? Did you run into trouble with the integral or something else? Also, this clearly cannot be solved without knowing the nature of the dependence between $X$ and $Y$ (consider e.g. the case of independent variables and the case $X=Y$ - they clearly have different answers). Do you know the joint distribution?

Comment: I guess I'm having trouble finding that integral. I tried re-writing the conditional distribution in terms of the joint distribution but then since $X$ and $Y$ are not independent I'm not sure how to find that joint distribution. i.e. $\int_a^{\infty}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} x \frac{f_{X,Y}(x,y)}{f_Y(y)} dx \ dy$. Also does it work to simply integrate $Y$ over $a$ to $\infty$?

Comment: In this case I don't know the nature of the dependence between $X$ and $Y$. Maybe my question should be is it possible to find this expectation for a general dependence? For example, I found a source [here](https://www.probabilitycourse.com/chapter5/5_3_2_bivariate_normal_dist.php) which gives $E[X | Y = y]$ for bivariate normal $X, Y$ with correlation $\rho$. Essentially I'm wondering how to find this for $Y \geq y$ not just $Y = y$.

Comment: The result I'm referring to in the link in the previous comment is theorem 5.4 near the bottom of the page. It states $E[X | Y = y] = \mu_X + \rho\sigma_X\frac{y-\mu_Y}{\sigma_Y}$ for bivariate normal $X, Y$ with correlation $\rho$

Comment: See https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/385423/119261 and linked posts.

Comment: That’s very helpful thank you!